# gitlab container registry: how to test that it's set up and working?

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

I'm trying to push for the first time to a gitlab project container registry.
I am not a gitlab administrator so I can't change global settings.  But as far as my project is concerned I've made sure that I have a personal access token created for the project.
When I try to run my pipeline, it fails with a 404 error.  I've recreated the steps just on the commandline to simplify things.  here's what the output looks like:

```
PS /Users/me/src/pipelinetests> docker login -u widgetsProjectAccessToken -p asdf mygitserver.org/myusername/pipelinetests

WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded

PS /Users/me/src/pipelinetests> docker build -t mygitserver.org/myusername/pipelinetests:widgetsimage .

[+] Building 190.4s (12/12) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 21.82kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64@sha256:1ee95620598b9afa3046d356bb7f7863e1602075dd407c790c34d0a9833acc73                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64@sha256:1ee95620598b9afa3046d356bb7f7863e1602075dd407c790c34d0a9833acc73                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] RUN apt update && apt-get install vim -y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [3/7] COPY . /builds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => [4/7] RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           93.2s
 => [5/7] RUN apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             25.7s
 => [6/7] RUN apt-get install nodejs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      13.0s 
 => [7/7] RUN npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              48.4s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     9.7s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    9.6s 
 => => writing image sha256:2f30a1f69f875df9e4645bea95247e7f8678da89d2da04524d0fc570e3e1ce4e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => naming to mygitserver.org/myusername/pipelinetests:widgetsimage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
PS /Users/me/src/pipelinetests> docker push mygitserver.org/myusername/pipelinetests:widgetsimage

The push refers to repository [mygitserver.org/myusername/pipelinetests]
0ee173286353: Preparing 
4c70ac952b79: Preparing 
b00534d89ac6: Preparing 
b7482490dd9f: Preparing 
ea13d436bb8a: Preparing 
120468cee518: Waiting 
fd6a5c73e987: Waiting 
e4869730bdcc: Waiting 
c782777c8a5d: Waiting 
a45a618792f0: Waiting 
6c946b32cfe2: Waiting 
7dd4a3e7d836: Waiting 
20147d2db13c: Waiting 
9c1b6dd6c1e6: Waiting 
error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <meta content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1\" name=\"viewport\">\n  <title>The page you're looking for could not be found (404)</title>\n  <style>\n    body {\n      color: #666;\n      text-align: center;\n      font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n      margin: auto;\n      font-size: 14px;\n    }\n\n    h1 {\n      font-size: 56px;\n      line-height: 100px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #456;\n    }\n\n    h2 {\n      font-size: 24px;\n      color: #666;\n      line-height: 1.5em;\n    }\n\n    h3 {\n      color: #456;\n      font-size: 20px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      line-height: 28px;\n    }\n\n    hr {\n      max-width: 800px;\n      margin: 18px auto;\n      border: 0;\n      border-top: 1px solid #EEE;\n      border-bottom: 1px solid white;\n    }\n\n    img {\n      max-width: 40vw;\n      display: block;\n      margin: 40px auto;\n    }\n\n    a {\n      line-height: 100px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #4A8BEE;\n      font-size: 18px;\n      text-decoration: none;\n    }\n\n    .container {\n      margin: auto 20px;\n    }\n\n    .go-back {\n      display: none;\n    }\n\n  </style>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n  <a href=\"/\">\n    <img src=\"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjEwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIxMCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIxMCAyMTAiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTEwNS4wNjE0IDIwMy42NTVsMzguNjQtMTE4LjkyMWgtNzcuMjhsMzguNjQgMTE4LjkyMXoiIGZpbGw9IiNlMjQzMjkiLz4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMTA1LjA2MTQgMjAzLjY1NDhsLTM4LjY0LTExOC45MjFoLTU0LjE1M2w5Mi43OTMgMTE4LjkyMXoiIGZpbGw9IiNmYzZkMjYiLz4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMTIuMjY4NSA4NC43MzQxbC0xMS43NDIgMzYuMTM5Yy0xLjA3MSAzLjI5Ni4xMDIgNi45MDcgMi45MDYgOC45NDRsMTAxLjYyOSA3My44MzgtOTIuNzkzLTExOC45MjF6IiBmaWxsPSIjZmNhMzI2Ii8+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTEyLjI2ODUgODQuNzM0Mmg1NC4xNTNsLTIzLjI3My03MS42MjVjLTEuMTk3LTMuNjg2LTYuNDExLTMuNjg1LTcuNjA4IDBsLTIzLjI3MiA3MS42MjV6IiBmaWxsPSIjZTI0MzI5Ii8+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTEwNS4wNjE0IDIwMy42NTQ4bDM4LjY0LTExOC45MjFoNTQuMTUzbC05Mi43OTMgMTE4LjkyMXoiIGZpbGw9IiNmYzZkMjYiLz4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMTk3Ljg1NDQgODQuNzM0MWwxMS43NDIgMzYuMTM5YzEuMDcxIDMuMjk2LS4xMDIgNi45MDctMi45MDYgOC45NDRsLTEwMS42MjkgNzMuODM4IDkyLjc5My0xMTguOTIxeiIgZmlsbD0iI2ZjYTMyNiIvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xOTcuODU0NCA4NC43MzQyaC01NC4xNTNsMjMuMjczLTcxLjYyNWMxLjE5Ny0zLjY4NiA2LjQxMS0zLjY4NSA3LjYwOCAwbDIzLjI3MiA3MS42MjV6IiBmaWxsPSIjZTI0MzI5Ii8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=\"\n       alt=\"GitLab Logo\" />\n  </a>\n  <h1>\n    404\n  </h1>\n  <div class=\"container\">\n    <h3>The page could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.</h3>\n    <hr />\n    <p>The resource that you are attempting to access does not exist or you don't have the necessary permissions to view it.</p>\n    <p>Make sure the address is correct and that the page hasn't moved.</p>\n    <p>Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake.</p>\n    <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\" class=\"js-go-back go-back\">Go back</a>\n  </div>\n  <script>\n    (function () {\n      var goBack = document.querySelector('.js-go-back');\n\n      if (history.length > 1) {\n        goBack.style.display = 'inline';\n      }\n    })();\n  </script>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

**What I've Done so far**

I've made sure that my project visibility and the settings are correct:

[image]

I've also created the personal access token - which the successful login proves.

**Questions**

In googling, it seems that some people found their container registry wasn't actually set up properly.  I'm not sure how to test that if I'm not a global admin.
So my first question is do you know of any other way I can test to make sure that it's a config issue?

If we assume it's actually set up correctly, could it just be that I haven't specified the correct port in my push command?  Like if the admin chose a non standard port, could that be the issue?

Are there other trees I should be barking up?

**EDIT 1**

These are the options under Packages & Registries

[image]

Comment: Please do not ask duplicate questions https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15831/gitlab-project-registry-docker-push-fails-with-invalid-reference-format-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitlab project registry - docker push fails with invalid reference format error message](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15831/gitlab-project-registry-docker-push-fails-with-invalid-reference-format-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not pushing to the right port.

When you go to the project space, and then go to your container registry `/container_registry` (or click under **Packages & Registries** → **Container Registry**

[image: Menus hove]

Or, like this if you prefer to click on **Packages & Registries**

[image: Menu click]

On this page you should see a bunch of links, one of them should have something like this,

```
docker push domain:5050/myusername/pipelinetests
```

You want to be sure you're including that `:5050`. That's the defualt port for the [GitLab Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html). It looks like from that error, that you're targeting the actual project page.

Comment: ok so under package & registries, i don't even have Container Registry.  I only have package & infrastructure as options.  I guess that's the smoking gun?  I assumed it would go under package registry.  Please see my EDIT 1 for new screenshot

Comment: @dot that would be a smoking gun, imho yes. I put a copy of the menu above.